# UpdateOnStatusChange: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.StringException: Error

Tags: apex, trigger, error

Trigger to insert record into another object based on criteria

### Code

```
trigger UpdateOnStatusChange on Object1__c (after update) {
List<Object2__c> ListOfIds = new List<Object2__c>();

for(Object1__c o1: trigger.new)
{
    if(o1.Status__c == 'Closed')
    {
        for(Object1__c o12: [select name,country__c from Object1__c where Id =: o1.Id])
        {
            ListOfIds.add(new Object2__c(name=o12.name,
                                         country__c = o12.country__c));
        }
    }
    
    try
    {
        if(!ListOfIds.isEmpty() )
       insert ListOfIds;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

}

Getting the above error, can someone mention whats wrong in my code above and where i need to improve my coding skills...
(Note)- The above code is not for bulk queries.

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: Please try to use relevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers to improve your coding skills:

1. Do not ever write a query in a loop - there is always a better way!
2. Do not catch and ignore exceptions. Catching the error and writing the message to the debug log is not beneficial to the user who experiences the problem.

   - Either do absolutely nothing and let the error surface, or
   - catch the exceptions and use the appropriate error handling techniques: `.addError()`, `ApexPages.addMessages()` etc. to display the problem.

Some good reading material on
[Apex Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)

---

Here's a simpler version of your trigger code:

```
trigger UpdateOnStatusChange on Object1__c (after update) {

    // the list of items to be inserted
    List<Object2__c> object2sToInsert = new List<Object2__c>();

    // the queried list of items matching our criteria which were in this trigger collection
    // this list will never be null
    List<Object1__c> closedObject1s = [SELECT Id
                                            , Name
                                            , Country__c
                                        FROM Object1__c
                                        WHERE Status__c = 'Closed' 
                                            AND Id IN Trigger.newMap.keyset()];

    // create a new record for each item in the result
    for (Object1__c closedObject1 : closedObject1s) {
        object2sToInsert.add(new Object2__c(Name = closedObject1.Name, Country__c = closedObject1.Country__c));
    }

    // do _not_ catch and ignore errors
    /* (catching and writing to the debug log is ignoring) */
    if (!object2sToInsert.isEmpty()) {
        insert object2sToInsert;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
trigger UpdateOnStatusChange on Object1__c (after update) 
{
List<Object2__c> ListOfIds = new List<Object2__c>();

for(Object1__c o1: trigger.new)

{

    if(o1.Status__c == 'Closed')

    {
        Object2__c tmpObj2 = new Object2__c (name=o1.name,country__c = o1.country__c);
        ListOfIds.add(tmpObj2);
    }
}

    try
    {
        if(!ListOfIds.isEmpty() )
       insert ListOfIds;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: The above code has no errors but the **fields in the Object2__c are not created after the status is updated to 'Closed'**... _no new records are create_  <br/>
**Note that the Object1__c and Object2__c have no relation**

Comment: you don't need any relationship to create a new record based on condition

Comment: Also since you have caught the exception i recommend checking logs to see any message .you can use system.debug to get message system.debug('ERROR_MESSAGE'+e.getMessage()); in catch block